# block requests by user hostname using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ip, hostname

Recently, my wordpress website has been experiencing a spike in hack attempts by various IPs but they all have the same user Hostname:

A user with IP address xxx.xxx.xx.x has been locked out from the signing in or using the password recovery form for the following reason: Used an invalid username to try to sign in.
User IP: 91.121.156.62
User hostname: ks359219.**badhost.com**

A user with IP address xxx.xxx.xx.x has been locked out from the signing in or using the password recovery form for the following reason: Used an invalid username to try to sign in.
User IP: 5.135.182.147
User hostname: ks3289006.**badhost.com**

A user with IP address xxx.xxx.xx.x has been locked out from the signing in or using the password recovery form for the following reason: Used an invalid username to try to sign in.
User IP: 5.135.185.89
User hostname: ks3290602.**badhost.com**

A user with IP address xxx.xxx.xx.x has been locked out from the signing in or using the password recovery form for the following reason: Used an invalid username to try to sign in.
User IP: 5.39.86.162
User hostname: ks3273571.**badhost.com**

The security plugin I am using seems to be fending them off, but I would like to be able to block all requests from ANY IP that is associated with the user hostname using a wildcard like xxx.**badhost.com**

The plugin lets me block a range of IPs such as 123.12.1.* but not hostnames. What would be the best way to block these hacking attempts? .htaccess? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this Apache doc page for examples of what you might want to do. It covers most cases of redirecting, blocking, etc. from direct domains and referring sites.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html#blocked-inline-images

Answer (score 0):

For WordPress you can use VSF Simple block http://wordpress.org/plugins/vsf-simple-block/

In Block Rules settings enter the part of the hostname string you want to block e.g. badhost.com

Bear in mind this is an active plugin, so does use some server resources and database queries for each lookup request, but we haven't found it too heavy.

PS - from the ks. part of the example I have a good idea of the hosts you wantto ban - I agree with you, these hosts are bad news - Ban them.... :)

Answer (score -1):

If you do `whois ks3273571.badhost.com`, it'll tell you the NetRange and CIDR for that ISP's netblock.

For example, `whois 69.59.197.21` (StackOverflow) reports:

```
NetRange:       69.59.192.0 - 69.59.223.255
CIDR:           69.59.192.0/19
```

Comment: where do you do whois? on a server?